# Improvements to Documentation tag dashboard

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation

There are two parts of the dashboard that don't make sense to me:

First, the action counter - why do we need this? What does this even mean? Actions today? In the last hour?

[image]

Second, the proposed changes queue is showing the newest entries on top. Why?
 By default it should start with the oldest changes, because if they don't get reviewed soon there will be new drafts that are going to have very similar changes. Making this as a setting when viewing all proposed changes would also be good.

Comment: "it should start with the oldest changes" **this**.